# iOS 10 UIKit Zombie Crash, Worked Fine in iOS 7-9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, uikit

We've got an app that's fairly large now, and we recently upgraded to iOS 10. In doing so, a new bug was introduced, and we're at a loss for how to solve it.

The crash itself occurs during a call to layoutIfNeeded(). However, the crash does not occur unless the layoutIfNeeded() call is contained inside a UIView.animateWithDuration() block. No amount of weak referencing, delays, or dispatch calls seems to have any effect. The same crash can be triggered during a call to [super viewWillTransitionToSizeWithTransitionCoordinator].

"An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'Bubble' object (zombie) at address: 0x10924f030."

Enabling Zombies shows that we have a Release call going to one of our UIView subclasses, which we've named Bubble. Nothing too special there, some layout constraints and a gesture recognizer.

The Instruments app hasn't helped much, nor has the new visual memory debugger in Xcode 8 (though it is awesome, surprisingly little documentation on the feature).

I've included a [screenshot of Zombies during the crash here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtSgq.jpg). While I know the retain count can be misleading, there are certainly some confusing points to the trace, and we could really use some help diagnosing this.

Again, this code worked fine before iOS 10. We've been unable to find any notes from Apple about underlying changes to UIKit that may have had an effect.

Some more brief info: [Bubble cleanBubbles] simply iterates over the subviews of any view passed in, and removes the subview if its a Bubble class.

Apologies on certain violations of naming conventions, I'm sure there's plenty to criticize!

Thanks